# Delete AD users via CSV using PowerShell and outputting result

Tags: powershell, csv, automation

I would like to delete number of AD users by providing list of usernames in CSV file and outputting the results to a CSV.

I can do this via single command:

```
Remove-ADUser -Identity Username1
```

I currently have this script:

```
$Users = Import-Csv 'c:\temp\DeleteADUsers.csv'
Foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    Try
    {
    # Verify that users from your CSV exist in Active Directory
    Get-ADUser $User -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
    Remove-ADUser $User
    }
    Catch
    {
    Write-Host "Username '$User' not found in Active Directory"
    }
}
```

I was wondering if someone could assist in help with altering the code incorporating CSV file like this:

[image: New CSV formant]

Also able to assist in outputting the results to CSV file.

**UPDATE 1**

I have tried this code:

```
$Users = Import-Csv 'c:\temp\DeleteADUsers.csv'
$logPath = 'c:\temp\out.log'

foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    Try
    {
        if($User.Delete -ne 'Yes'){
            # not marked for deletion, let's skip it
            continue
           "Username '$User' skipped as it is not marked for deletion" |Tee-Object -LiteralPath $logPath
        }
        # Verify that users from your CSV exist in Active Directory
        Get-ADUser $User.sAMAccountName -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
        Remove-ADUser $User.sAMAccountName
       "User '$User' removed from Active Directory" |Tee-Object -LiteralPath $logPath
    }
    Catch
    {
       "Username '$User' not found in Active Directory" |Tee-Object -LiteralPath $logPath
    }
}
```

This is the style of my CSV:

[image: CSV New Style]

When I run the code I get no error or output on the screen and no log file.

This is all I get in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DeleteADUsers.ps1

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

The user is not deleted when checking AD.

Please assist.

**UPDATE 2**

Sorry guys I figured it out reverted back to the CSV style I have and this fixed the issue.

Re-read the code properly and found the issue DUH....

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Import-Csv` will automatically parse each row and spit out objects with property names corresponding to the column headers in the CSV.

That means you can use `$User.sAMAccountName` to refer to the value in the `sAMAccountName` column:

```
$Users = Import-Csv 'c:\temp\DeleteADUsers.csv'
$logPath = 'path\to\out.log'

foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    Try
    {
        if($User.Delete -ne 'Yes'){
            # not marked for deletion, let's skip it
            continue
           "Username '$User' skipped as it is not marked for deletion" |Tee-Object -LiteralPath $logPath
        }
        # Verify that users from your CSV exist in Active Directory
        Get-ADUser $User.sAMAccountName -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
        Remove-ADUser $User.sAMAccountName
       "User '$User' removed from Active Directory" |Tee-Object -LiteralPath $logPath
    }
    Catch
    {
       "Username '$User' not found in Active Directory" |Tee-Object -LiteralPath $logPath
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What about outputting the results to a CSV?

Comment: What output? `Remove-ADUser` doesn't return anything :)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being clear for example I would like it to echo "Username1 has been deleted" or "Username not found in Active Directory" these echo for each user could be outputted to CSV if possible? I hope I make sense.

Comment: The CSV part doesn't make any sense, but writing to a log file does :)

Comment: Thanks for modding the code much appreciated my friend!